# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have got the dreaded VerifyCsrfToken error in my Laravel 5.2 project.

Relevant codes are below:

**Route which is throwing the error**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::resource('register', 'RegisterController');
});
```

Error is thrown when I try to register a new user using POST request

**Register Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return AppUser::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('name'),
        'contact_number' => $request->input('contact_number'),
        'api_token' => str_random(60),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    ]);
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "email": "test.name",
  "contact_number": "654987123",
  "updated_at": "2016-10-06 06:30:26",
  "created_at": "2016-10-06 06:30:26",
  "id": 4
}
```

What makes my question different from the other VerifyCsrf mismatch questions are, I don't have a form to add a `{{ csrf_token() }}` hidden field. I just sent the request using Postman (and curl) and the user needs to be registered.

When I do the following edit on `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
protected $except = [
    '/*'
    //
];
```

The error disappears and it works as it should, but I don't think is the recommended way.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and YES adding "/*" is not at all recommended way.

Comment: @GauravDave from the above codes, all I want to do is register the user (this was just a test not the final version) so I am sending the required data in the body using postman and link is `localhost:8000/register`. And I want the data to get entered into the database.

Comment: Who downvoted this :/

Comment: do you use some javascript? or just php? If php, use Form helper, it will prepare csrf for you.

Comment: `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` add this to your blade if you don't use form.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 I'm using only php but my project does not have any forms

Comment: @SanzeebAryal my project does not have any views either, though only the default Laravel 5 view. Should I still add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` to the default blade?

Comment: It would be great if someone could tell me why this is getting downvoted because in my opinion, I checked all the required boxes in asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the token in the root blade file. if you are using only default view, then may be in `layout/main.blade.php`

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If using jQuery, you can now instruct it to include the token in all request headers.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
   });
```

If you still get errors follow: https://gist.github.com/ethanstenis/3cc78c1d097680ac7ef0

Comment: Hats off to you, sir. Much obliged. I followed the instructions in the github post and it works now on Postman. If I include a header with my http request, my api should work, right?

Comment: i'm glad this helped.