# TokenMismatchException in Postman even with token entered

Tags: laravel, postman

I'm trying to do a simple PUT in the Postman Mac app to a Laravel 5.3 update web route.

Every time I do, I'm given a `TokenMismatchException` error.

I've tried:

- Putting the token value in `_token` in the PUT body.
- Putting the token headers as `X-CSRF-TOKEN`.
- I've tried the Postman Interceptor with the proxy on so that it auto-gathers the correct cookies and token when I submit the form I'm simulating on my dev site.
- I've tried a combination of all three of these.

None of this works.

Postman is normally a very valuable tool but Laravel seems to be defeating it (and me) at the moment.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you actually need x-csrf-token while using postman?

Comment: I get the TokenMismatchException if I do or don't include it.

Comment: my guess is that since its not a browser, it might be losing track of sent _token for that request, but im not sure how you should handle it.

Comment: have you tried storing token in meta tag in blade view http://stackoverflow.com/a/39890093/5608921?

Comment: I asked if you need the token, since you can disable CSRF middleware while testing and not worry about it at all...

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing sending token in 'Authorization' header for the request in postman in this format:

Authorization: Bearer {token here}

I have attached the screenshot here as well.[image]

Comment: This site doesn't have an `Authorization` token. I'm not testing the API side of things.

Comment: Make sure you have the write permission configured for storage/framework/sessions folder. As the token is generated and stored in the session for comparing, can be a reason that session is not writable or the path of the session storage is not configured properly.

Comment: Sessions work fine and all permissions are correct. The app itself functions without issue. It is only when I try to test routes through Postman that I'm running into a problem.